# Python/Django - *args as list

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm using the .order_by() method/function; however, I want to construct the order_by fields dynamically.  The problem is .order_by() expects to receive a string or buffer.  So, I can't build a list or tuple or object to send to the function.  How can I achieve this goal?

I wanted to do something like:

```
field_list = []
for field in fields:
  field_list.append( field )
model.objects.all().order_by( field_list )
```

???

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `model.objects.all().order_by(*field_list)`; this is due to the fact that `order_by` accepts multiple string arguments, not lists of multiple strings.

See [This chapter in djangobook, search for `order_by`](http://www.djangobook.com/en/1.0/chapter05/), and [this](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) for arguments unpacking.

Comment: Ahhh!  Very good.  For the sake of curiosity, do you know where there is any documentation on this?  It'll help me and others :)